# Test and validation data coming null

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I want to divide a signal into train, validate and test data randomly. I did it as

```
[y1,Fs1,nbits1,readinfo1]=wavread('src04.wav');
[y2,Fs2,nbits2,readinfo2]=wavread('tgt04.wav');
[trainV1,valV1,testV1,trainInd,valInd,testInd] = dividerand(y1,0.6,0.2,0.2);
[trainV2,valV2,testV2] = divideind(y2,trainInd,valInd,testInd);
```

But the validation and test data (valV1, testV1 and valV2, tetsV2) are being displayed as empty matrix.

How can I obtain the validation and test data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that 'y1' has wrong shape. Try transposing y1:

```
[trainV1,valV1,testV1,trainInd,valInd,testInd] = dividerand(y1',0.6,0.2,0.2);
```

Same for 'y2'